# Sumo Warning in netedit

Tags: warnings, sumo

I am very new to Sumo. I am doing a simple simulation from tutorial in sumo documentation and I face a warining which stops me. Warning: Double edges aren't allowed. Does anyone know what is it and how can I get rid of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning occurs on creating a route for a vehicle if you click twice on the same edge in direct succession. It essentially means that you cannot drive the same edge again (without driving other edges inbetween).